# Access getsupportfragmentmanager() inside listActivity for API -10

Tags: android, android-fragments, listactivity

I want to use
 `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getsupportfragmentmanager();` 
inside listActivity. I'm getting the following error/warning `Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.app.ListActivity#getFragmentManager`and due to Api level, can not use ListFragment. Can anybody please help me how to use `FragmentManager` inside ListActivity for API level 10.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that you have `imported android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`,
and your activity extended from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: My activity already extends ListActivity, thus I can not extent FragmentedActivity and also due to API-10 constrain I can not use ListFragment.

Comment: Fragment are using in 2 case: 1 Android 3.0.0+ or support library classes. In you case you need to extend of FragmentActivity and implement ListFragment for your ListView

Comment: Thank you sir, for helping me. `ListFragment` is added in API 11 where my min is API 10. Hope I explained you correctly.

Comment: ListFragment is added in support library also